# Advanced Custom Fields | Using a repeater plus sub fields to display images

Tags: loops, while-loop

```
        <?php if(get_field('bsd_multi_channel_communications')): ?>
            <ul>
            <?php while(has_sub_field('bsd_multi_channel_communications')): ?>
                <div id="multi-channel-wrapper">
                    <ul>    
                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('bsd_multi_channel_images'); ?>" alt="" />    
                        <li><?php the_sub_field('bsd_multi_channel_title'); ?><li>
                        <li><?php the_sub_field('bsd_multi_channel_text'); ?></li>
                        <li><?php the_sub_field('bsd_multi_channel_start'); ?></li>
                    </ul><!-- end bsd-home-list-control -->
                </div><!-- end multi-channel-wrapper --> 
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

For some reason my links are broken when I try to display the  in the while loop. Everything else works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

When you say your links are broken, do you mean image src? If so, you probably need to check what the return value is for the image field. There are three options, Image Object, Image URL and Image ID; of these, the only one you can place directly in an img tag is "Image URL".

If you know you are uploading the image at the correct size, Image URL works. If you're counting on WordPress cropping/resizing to a specific size, the easiest approach is Image Object, which will return an array that includes URL's for all of the image sizes as well as alt and title text.

--

Another problem you're going to run into, throwing an ID into a while loop. An ID should be used only once per page.

Comment: Thanks Allen, I got it to work now. It was an option setting with advanced custom fields like you mentioned.